# Room @Transaction not working with Flowable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2

I have a problem with using `@Transaction` annotation on my data source method. Looks like this annotation not working in my case.

I have a usual room database with DAO

```
@Database(entities = [MyEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myDao(): MyDao
}

@Dao
interface myDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(list: List<MyEntity>)
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyEntity")
    fun observe(): Flowable<List<MyEntity>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM MyEntity")
    fun clear()
}
```

Problem appears in my data source when I do consistently `clear()` and `insertAll()`

```
class MyDataSource(database: MyDatabase) {
    private val myDao = database.myDao()

    @Transaction
    fun updateMyEntity(items: List<MyEntity>) {
        myDao.clear()
        myDao.insertAll(items)
    }

    fun observeMyEntity(): Flowable<List<MyEntity>> {
        return myDao.observe()
    }
}
```

When I call `updateMyEntity()`, I get two results in my subscription on `oberveMyEntity()`. The first result is empty list and the second one is inserted list. I expected to get only inserted list as I added annotation `@Transaction` to method `updateMyEntity()`. Is this annotation not working in my case?

I saw in docs the following information, but I am not sure is it my case or not.

> If the query is asynchronous (e.g. returns a {@link androidx.lifecycle.LiveData LiveData}
> or RxJava {@code Flowable}), the transaction is properly handled when the query is run, not when
> the method is called.
>
> Putting this annotation on an {@link Insert}, {@link Update} or {@link Delete} method has no
> impact because those methods are always run inside a transaction. Similarly, if a method is
> annotated with {@link Query} but runs an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement, it is automatically wrapped in a transaction and this annotation has no effect.

The problem disappears if make `database` a property and wrap calls `clear()` and `insertAll()` with `database.runInTransaction { }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Transaction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction) can only be used for `Dao` methods